# rich internet application solutions for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rich-internet-application

I am wondering what are the possible rich internet application solutions that goes well with ruby or if there is a GWT equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IronRuby with Silverlight to create a rich Internet app.
If you add a service reference for your web services, IronRuby can also call your SOAP services.

See:

- [Walk-through: Silverlight Flickr Client in IronRuby](http://blog.jimmy.schementi.com/2008/08/walk-through-silverlight-flickr-client.html)
- [IronNails = Silverlight + IronRuby + Patterns](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/08/04/ironruby-and-silverlight-with-ironnails.aspx)
- [From Ruby Silverlight to Ruby Web Service (with a touch of spice)](http://blog.monnet-usa.com/?p=20)

Answer (score 2):

With ExtJS (a RIA javascript framework) there is [netzke](http://github.com/skozlov/netzke/tree/master)

[screencast](http://vimeo.com/4517750)

Answer (score 0):

Flex it's quite a good RIA environment and framework and it works pretty good with Rails (especially if you use REST to expose and receive functionality).

There is a good book [Flexible Rails](http://www.manning.com/armstrong/) that goes through the process. Check out also [FlexonRails](http://flexonrails.net/) and [some examples of both working](http://www.flex888.com/358/10-flex-and-ruby-on-rails-integration-examples.html).

One of the advantages of using Flex is that is runs on the Flash Player, which is vastly installed on the majority of computers nowadays, and it's working model it's fairly good and easy to grasp.